# How do I gnereate Embed Code on Azure Bot Services for OAuth v2 in Slack

Tags: botframework, slack-api

Slack recently deprecated the bot scope in favor of more granular scopes. I have already migrated my app from the bot scope to granular scopes on the Slack' developer portal. I'm trying to get an embed code for my "Add to Slack" button. I'm trying to get the embed code from channel settings on Bot services as defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=abs

The embed code in my channel settings still point to Slack' legacy bot scope. The embed code is
https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=bot/oauth/.....

I'm expecting an embed code that points to the new granular scopes on oauth2, the URL i expect would be https://slack.com/oauthv2/authorize?scope=app_mentions:read....

Is there a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pointing back to the [GitHub equivalent](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/223).

You need to remove the the slack channel and then re-add it. This will give the V2 auth, and then you will be able to modify the scopes.